How to simulate Hercules on local IP address?
I would like to simulate a TCP server, using Hercules (by HW-Group).
When I configure the port (12714), netstat -aon | findstr "12714" shows me this result:

DOS Prompt>netstat -aon | findstr "12714"
TCP  0.0.0.0:12714  0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING  29408

Does anybody know how I can get TCP-server address "127.0.0.1:12714" instead of "0.0.0.0:12714" (or any other IP address, I just want to get rid of this broadcast address)?
The reason I ask: a bind() is done to that IP address/port, with the following exception as a result:
Communication.TcpConnection.Connect | TcpConnection: Connecting failed (127.0.0.1:12714):
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in its context
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at Server.Communication.TcpConnection.Connect() in 
C:\...Communication\TcpConnection.cs:line 60 

Thanks in advance

In this context it's not a broadcast address – it's the "all local addresses" wildcard address.
It is up to the listener program to specify which local address it wants to bind() to. If it doesn't specify any, then the socket is bound to all addresses belonging to the machine. Contact the program's developers to add such an option – or use something like ForceBindIP to inject the correct bind() call.
Any socket bound to the wildcard address automatically includes the loopback address, so if your program doesn't have the option to change what it binds to, and if your goal is to restrict the server, then the easiest method to make it "local only" is to keep it bound to 0.0.0.0 and use Windows Firewall (wf.msc) to block any unwanted incoming connections.

I've edited my question, adding the Exception I see when trying to bind() to that IP address/port.

@Dominique: Should your other program be trying to bind to the same address in the first place? It's the server – Hercules in this case – that is in control of the socket and should use bind(), while clients should only need connect() in most cases. (And even if the client needs to bind to a local address of its own, it's even more rare for it to bind to a specific client-side port.)

My program contains this line of source code: _socket.Bind(GetCurrentServerIpAddress()); and GetCurrentServerIpAddress returns return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.3.19"), 0);, does this mean that my program is the server and Hercules the client and how should I configure this whole thing? (Sorry that I'm asking but my previous colleague left in a bad atmosphere and I have no where to turn to)

Asking for that last IP address (again using netstat -aon) reveals: TCP  10.1.13.240:56918  192.168.3.19:8732  SYN_SENT  25576.

No, that looks like the type of bind() that a client would do – servers always specify a port to bind to (and optionally an address), while clients almost never bind to a specific port. But in both cases, an address given to bind() would have to be local to that side of the connection – the client binds to its own local address, not to the server's, and vice versa – so your example looks particularly odd, unless the server and the client are supposed to be on the exact same machine.

I can assure you that both are on different machines: my program is a server application, performing some management tasks, while the other machines are balances, fixed on automatic vehicles, and it's the idea that the weights from the balances are sent over TCP sockets to my server application.

That kind of makes sense, though the port being 0 is still odd – I assume it's a server program that additionally makes some connections as a client (in which case there would be two separate bind calls)? Did your backtrace come from the same program? Is 192.168.3.19 the address of the system where the server program is supposed to run, or is it the address of one of the balances?

That "192.168" IP address is the address of the computer, where my server application will be running. Obviously, this means that I must alter that IP address to the address of my local development machine for testing purposes, I'll try this right away.

Right – you can only bind() to an address belonging to the local machine; or do it like Hercules and specify 0.0.0.0 to bind to all local addresses (the clients will not be able to tell the difference).

This is what I did: I have altered the IP addresses of the balances to my local IP address, then I opened a TCP Server connection in Hercules on port 12714 (I'm confident the other, 12756, will work now too), and when sending a message over the connection, I have received it in my locally installed server application. THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR SUPPORT! (If you can find a way to put this stuff in an answer, I'll upvote and accept it.)

Oops, I was that stressed out by the whole situation I had forgotten that we are commenting on your answer, so no need to write another answer :-)
